# I want to show my contact form slowly but it is not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress

```
$("#contect_exa").click(function() { 
  $(".contact_form").show(1000);
  });
});
```

How can I show my contact form slowly? `Show()` function is working but but given time is not working.

Comment: There is no apparent reason for this not to be working unless you're not hiding it by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code delay is only 1 second(1000 milliseconds) increase it for showing it slowly or you can use **[`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)** or **[`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/)** with delay

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $("#div").show(5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">click</button>
<div style="display:none;background:red;width:50px;height:50px;" id="div"></div>
```

or

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $("#div").fadeIn(5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">click</button>
<div style="display:none;background:red;width:50px;height:50px;" id="div"></div>
```

Or

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  $("#div").slideDown(1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">click</button>
<div style="display:none;background:red;width:50px;height:50px;" id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Time interval will work for show() or hide() methods.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Contact").hide();

    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("#Contact").show(2000);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Contact">
<input type="text"><br/>
<input type="text"><br/>
<input type="text"><br/>
<input type="text">
</div>
<button id="show">Show</button>
</body>
</html>
```

for more: http://api.jquery.com/show/